# Can't get location when loading app, but when passing from another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

What am I doing wrong? I know the code works since I get the location in the cell when returning from another view controller but it does not come up when the app loads first time. I've been staring myself blind on this!

Any help appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var arrayLocations:[[Double]] = [[27.1750199, 78.0399665]]

var annotationAddress = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    }

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if !arrayLocations.isEmpty {

        arrayLocations = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayLocations") as? [[Double]] ?? [[Double]]()
        print("Table view is loaded")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayLocations.count

}

override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    getLocationAddress(location: CLLocation(latitude: arrayLocations[indexPath.row][0], longitude: arrayLocations[indexPath.row][1]))

    cell.textLabel?.text = annotationAddress

    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // activeRow = indexPath.row

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMapViewController", sender: nil)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toMapViewController" {

        let mapViewController = segue.destination as! MapViewController

        mapViewController.arrayLocations = arrayLocations

    }
}

func getLocationAddress(location: CLLocation) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error!)

        } else {

            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {

                var address = ""


                if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {

                    address += placemark.subThoroughfare! + " "

                }

                if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {

                    address += placemark.thoroughfare!

                }

                self.annotationAddress = address

                if self.annotationAddress.isEmpty {

                    self.annotationAddress = "Lat: \(location.coordinate.latitude) and Lon: \(location.coordinate.longitude)"

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change as below :

```
override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    getLocationAddress(location: CLLocation(latitude: arrayLocations[indexPath.row][0], longitude: arrayLocations[indexPath.row][1]), cell : cell)


    return cell

}
```

**Add one parameter for cell in getLocationAddress function**

```
func getLocationAddress(location: CLLocation, cell: UITableViewCell) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error!)

        } else {

            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {

                var address = ""


                if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {

                    address += placemark.subThoroughfare! + " "

                }

                if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {

                    address += placemark.thoroughfare!

                }

                self.annotationAddress = address

                if self.annotationAddress.isEmpty {

                    self.annotationAddress = "Lat: \(location.coordinate.latitude) and Lon: \(location.coordinate.longitude)"

                }
                   cell.textLabel?.text = annotationAddress
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Worked a treat! Now I just need to figure out why it worked... ;)

Comment: It is worked because of reverseGeocodeLocation asynchronous calling so.

Answer (score 1):

The method `reverseGeocodeLocation` is an async call. This means that when your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method calls `getLocationAddress`, it moves on and displays the cell. When `reverseGeocodeLocation` comes back with a response, no one is telling the table to reload. Then you move away to another view and come back, your `viewDidAppear` calls `reloadData` causing the cells to display the values. Another thing to note here is that in this instance, your cells are displaying the values from the previous request (before you moved to the next viewController) not the current one(Yeah! it sends another request every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called).

You can either use a `Promise` library to solve this issue or call `reloadData` in the `else` block of your completion handler

Comment: When an async call finishes, usually it calls the `completion handler`. The code block contained inside the curly braces after `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location)` in your code is a `completion block` that gets passed to the method so the method knows what to do when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getLocationAddress` should return some value that would give your cell label some value or you could just reload table in `getLocationAddress`

Comment: It does. It updates the annotationAddress variable. I didn't manage to return a value without throwing an error so this was the easiest solution.

Comment: Great! You can accept this as an answer if it worked for you :)